# Display PDF in angular from rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, pdf

i get the data from a REST service. I obtain the base64 and the content type of the file. Then i convert the base64 to Arraybuffer using this function.

```
        function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
        var len = binary_string.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes.buffer;
    }
```

then i create a blob with the Arraybuffer and the content type.

```
        var pru = base64ToArrayBuffer($scope.listaDocumentosById[1].docto);
        var blob = new Blob([pru], {type: $scope.listaDocumentosById[1].tipo_docto});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $scope.content = fileURL;
```

finally i try to show in the HTML the blob using content as ng-model

```
<object ng-show="content" data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></object>
```

but i get the next error

The PDF document could not be loaded.

i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you inject the $sce service? You have to do that to disaply pdf .   After injecting, try this: $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);         Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Comment: still isn't working

Comment: could you create a plunker/fiddle to show your complete code?